# Pb using nsf's "gothic" (tcl/tk go binding) library under Mac

Tags: macos, binding, go, tcl

I have been using nsf's  "gothic" (tcl/tk go binding) libary under Linux for a while now : it works very well and is very convenient for adding a tcl/tck-based graphical interface to a Go application (more or less what Tkinter is to Python).

https://github.com/nsf/gothic

However, I experienced a few problems installing it under Mac.

In an attempt to solve that problem, I made the following modifications to my Mac development environment:

- Installed the latest version of Xcode.
- Removed "port" (port of the Linux tools for Mac) entirely and installed it from scratch to the latest version.
- Upgraded to the latest stable version of Go.

Now at least I can install "gothic" under Mac and it compiles without complaining.

I had to make the following changes to the `interpreter.go` file, so that the header directives point to the correct library location:

```
#cgo !tcl85 LDFLAGS: -L/opt/local/lib
#cgo !tcl85 LDFLAGS: -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6
#cgo !tcl85 CFLAGS:  -I/opt/local/include/tcl8.6
#cgo darwin tcl85 CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include
#cgo darwin tcl85 CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include/tcl8.6
```

instead of the original:

```
#cgo !tcl85 LDFLAGS: -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6
#cgo !tcl85 CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/tcl8.6
#cgo tcl85 LDFLAGS: -ltcl8.5 -ltk8.5
#cgo tcl85 CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/tcl8.5
#cgo darwin tcl85 CFLAGS: -I/opt/X11/include
```

So that is points to the correct libraries.

The current situation is that the examples do compile, without any warnings or error messages.

The problem is that the resulting executables only run correctly randomly, form time to time, but most of the time just "hangs" (displays an empty white rectangle where the interface should be) the execution of the program blocks.

In nsf's code the last statement which gets executed apparently (when the executable gets stuck) is the call to `Tk_Mainloop()`.

This is as far as I have come in trying to figure out what is going wrong.

So obviously, it is not a Go (golang) to Tcl binding problem.

It looks as if the "connection" between Tcl and Tk sometimes works and sometimes not in that context (whereas it works perfectly under Linux).

Has anybody had more success in using "gothic" on a mac (or possibly more experience with using tcl/tk bindings under mac) ?

If yes, would be very grateful for some help on how to proceed.

Thanks,

Comment: It could be the interaction between tk / X or Go doing something weird on mac, can you try with go 1.2 and tip?

Comment: Most new Tk code on OS X is probably targeting the Cocoa variety of the UI, so you probably should not link against the X11 version unless you really need to. Macports had some variant switch to do it.

Comment: Are you looking to build an X11 or Aqua (OSX native) Tk? Tk defaults to Aqua on OSX, because that tends to be what users mostly expect, but if you're porting code from Linux you probably need to use the X11 version. Otherwise any C code that does custom drawing will need to be _totally_ rewritten from scratch; though Tk hides it well, the X11 and Aqua/Cocoa APIs are utterly different. (That's one of the reasons why it's actually quite hard to develop Tk itself.)

Comment: I have attempted so far to recompile the Linux code with the libraries provided by "Ports" (without any modifications). It usually works, but not quite in this case.

Comment: Problem solved: I have, in the meantime installed :

- Yosemite (Mac OS X 10.10.1)
- The latest version of "Port" (https://www.macports.org/)
- XQuartz 2.7.7 and now it works

Nsf.s gothic (tcl/tk to Golang binding) library appers to work correctly on Mac now !

So the assumption that the problem was linked to the (late) implementation of  X11.app was correct !

Serge

Comment: Pb = Problem? ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the meantime installed :

- Yosemite (Mac OS X 10.10.1)
- The latest version of "Port" (https://www.macports.org/)
- XQuartz 2.7.7 and now it works

Nsf.s gothic (tcl/tk to Golang binding) library appers to work correctly on Mac now !

So the assumption that the problem was linked to the (late) implementation of  X11.app was correct !

Serge